# When a function field is a regular extension of the field of coefficients?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $A$ be an integral affine $k$-algebra with field of fractions $K$. I am wondering when the extension $K/k$ is regular. In particular, is the following statement correct?

> $K/k$ is regular $\iff$ $A$ is geometrically integral,
>   i.e. $A\otimes_k\overline{k}$ is a domain

**Edit:** By definition, an extension $K/k$ is regular $\iff$ $K$ is separable over $k$ and $k$ is algebraically closed in $K$. This is equivalent to saying that $K$ and $\overline{k}$ are linearly disjoint over $k$.

Comment: Please see the edited version of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a field extension $K/k$ is regular iff it is geometrically integral, the equivalence you are asking about is true and follows from the fact that a domain over $k$ is geometrically integral if and only if its fraction field $K=\operatorname {Frac}(A)$ is geometrically integral:

a) Of course if $K$ is geometrically integral then  $A$ will also be, since a subring of a domain is a domain:  $A\otimes_k L\subset K\otimes _k L $  where $L$ is an arbitrary extension of $k$.
b) The other direction is a bit more complicated: it results from Bourbaki's Algebra, Chapter 5, §17, Proposition 4.

[Note that the hypothesis that $A$ is an affine algebra (by which I suppose you mean finitely generated over $k$) is not necessary.]